# Letter recognition feature extraction

Tags: pattern-recognition, feature-engineering

I have few thousands letter's images which are all colored black on a white background. I wanted to extract their features so that it was possible to cluster them effectively.

My attempt was to divide an image on 25 parts, calculate black pixels to white pixels ratio in each part (if there were no white ones I assumed the ratio is twice the black pixels) and thus convert an image to a vector of 25 values. I also added a 26th attribute which denoted if an image represents a letter which has a dot/something else outside its 'body'. Then I used a k-centroids algorithm to cluster the data, but the results were highly unsatisfactory.

Is there any simple, yet effective way to do what I'm trying to do?

(Images are of different size, mainly with varying width (from 5 to 30 pixels) and rather stable height (29 to 31 pixels). As I said, they are all black and white.)

Comment: Have you tried exploring the data / features you constructed? I'm not surprised those features don't work well.

Comment: Are you sure you want clustering and not classification?

Comment: No, I'm not sure actually.

Comment: @gung What do you mean by exploring the data?

Comment: Look at the patterns of the features & how they relate to the letters.

Comment: Visualizing the data, maybe in [such a plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dXx1A.jpg) might be helpful. Note that you probably won't get such a nice distinction between classes with the current set of features, but it might give you some idea about which features are working good.

Comment: Ok, but do you have any other ideas what features I could add? Little really comes to my mind if all I have are black and white pixels... I could additionally calculate the number of closed loops, I read it is useful in char. recognition but that's it.

Comment: Your 26th feature could be improved with connected component analysis. Other than that, I'm not experienced with digit/letter recognition, so my best bet would be to search for relevant articles and check what features they have used. Or maybe someone will be nice enough to give a summary of such articles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using hand-tuned features, I'd suggest using some automated form of dimensionality reduction, which will automatically extract features from your data. There are many ways to do this, ranging from the simple, linear case (e.g. PCA) to complex, nonlinear 'manifold learning' algorithms (e.g. t-SNE). Neural networks (particularly variants like autoencoders) could also work well. All of the methods I just mentioned are unsupervised, which means that they don't use labels (in your case, you'd give the images as input, but you wouldn't specify what letters they represent). Unsupervised methods work by attempting to find 'structure' in the data; what this means varies from algorithm to algorithm. There's no guarantee that the images will form clusters around the letters they represent; whether this happens or not depends on the data and how structure is defined.

You'll probably find [this blog post](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-10-Visualizing-MNIST/) interesting. They run various dimensionality reduction methods on the MNIST dataset, which is a set of grayscale images of hand-drawn digits.

If you explicitly want the extracted features to cluster (or at least be separable) in terms of the letters they represent, then it might be better to use a supervised algorithm (i.e. to train a classifier). In your case, you'd give the training algorithm a set of images and a set of labels indicating the letters they represent. The training algorithm will attempt to learn a function (the classifier) that predicts the represented letter from the image. Some classifiers will give you a set of extracted features, and others won't. For example, a k nearest neighbors classifier won't, so it won't be useful for your purposes (assuming that what you want to do is examine the features).

A simple, linear, supervised method is linear discriminant analysis (LDA). It will give you a set of features that are linear combinations of your input pixels. It attempts to find the weights of these linear combinations such that, when the data are projected into the feature space, it's possible to linearly separate the data points in each class (i.e. to find hyperplanes that separate the images representing each letter). Note that it may not be possible to linearly separate the classes in this way, and LDA will try to do the best it can.

A more complicated, non-linear class of methods is supervised neural networks. In this case, the network would take an image as input, and output the predicted letter the image represents (or a probability distribution over possible letters). The network would be trained to correctly classify images of letters. You can think of the units (i.e. 'neurons') in each layer of the network as representing features of the input image. Therefore, if you want to use the network for feature extraction, simply take the vector of unit activations for some layer of the network.

Dimensionality reduction and supervised learning are enormous fields, but hopefully these few examples can help getting started looking for more methods.

Comment: And what do you understand as 'giving an image as an input'? Its pixels' representation? Doesn't it matter the images are differently sized? If I were to use a neural network, I'd need to have the same amount of features and if I use pixels, I don't.

Comment: Certain classes of neural networks can process variable-sized inputs (e.g. recurrent networks). But many methods (neural net or otherwise) require fixed-size inputs. A simple option is to zero-pad the images to the same size, trying to keep your letter roughly centered in the image. Then, use pixels as input.